# Letting user choose Email Client when they send an email in app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I am developing an app right now that has email functionality.
My problem is with the intent.createChooser not giving the proper options to the user.

```
fun send(context: Context) {
        val mIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        mIntent.type = "text/plain"
        mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf("temp@temp.com"))
        mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, _contactUiState.value.subject)
        mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, _contactUiState.value.message)

        try {
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mIntent, "Send Email"))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("Main", e.message!!)
        }
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that setting `mIntent.type` to "`text/plain`" gives options that isn't an email client. Setting `mIntent.data` to `Uri.parse("mailto:")` makes it so that options don't come up and it just chooses one for you. Setting both of them gives 0 options. How can I make it so that the only options that show up are email clients?

Comment: If one just comes up, it means that's the default email client set by the user.  So it just coming up is probably what you want.  If the user wishes to change their default email client, they can in settings.

Comment: However you can force the chooser as seen here:  https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending#AppChooser